# Spannable text is too wide for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a `TextView` with the font `sans-serif-light`. To link some words inside, I set a text as a `Spannable` like this:

```
final Spannable text = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
final Matcher matcher = PATTERN_TAG.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    text.setSpan(span, startIndex, endIndex, 0);
}
textView.setText(text);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

The `Span` that I apply sets the word's font to `sans-serif-medium` like this:

```
public abstract class ClickableTagSpan extends ClickableSpan {

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-medium", Typeface.NORMAL));
    }
}
```

[image: text get's cut off on the right edge]

The problem is that the text becomes too wide for the `TextView` in some rows since the width of the medium font is larger than the light font that was orginally set. The `TextView` simply cuts off the text on the right edge. How can I get the `TextView` to respect the correct width of the text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it by setting an additional `TypefaceSpan`, rather than modifying the `ClickableSpan`.

```
text.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndex, endIndex, 0);
text.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif-medium"), startIndex, endIndex, 0);
```

This makes the `TextView` correctly wrap the text.

Comment: Thanks man you're a pro. Also I found out that you can remove 

ds.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-medium", Typeface.NORMAL));

from your updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) method.